# Animate amp-img through position-observer: Failing with clip-path... Am I dumb?

Tags: amp-html, amp-img, amp-animation

html workers.

I am struggling with amp-html animation.

I want to animate an amp-img as it enter the viewport. So far so good. We have done that.
However: despite being referenced in the docs as working: This won't work.
Pug code:

```
<amp-animation id="fadeIn1" layout="nodisplay">
  script(type="application/json").
    [
      {
        "selector": ".fadein2",
        "duration": "3200ms",
        "delay": "111ms",
        "easing": "ease-out",
        "iterations": "1",
        "fill": "both",
        "keyframes": [
          {"transform": "translate3d(0px, 110px,0)","clip-path":"circle(100px)"},
          {"transform": "translate3d(0px, 0px,0) ","clip-path":"circle(200px)"}
        ]
      }
    ]
</amp-animation>
<amp-position-observer on="enter:fadeIn1.start" layout="nodisplay">
</amp-position-observer>
```

The image (in Pug)

```
amp-img.cover.fadein2.p0.m0.z4(src=require(`Images/${img4}`), alt=alt1, width="51", height="51", layout="responsive")|
```

The amp-img itself shows up quite fine and in transforming.
Just the cropping animation won't work. Did anyone of you succeed in doing that ?

Any hint about my stupidity would be helpful.
Any hint about a solution would be even better.

Cheers,
m

Comment: Hi, I still can't figure out if your animation works or not? What kind of "cropping animation" are we talking about?

Comment: It's actually quite straithforward.

The Image has to animate with a transform, and with a clip-animation at the same time...  however this seems not to work well.

Comment: I tried to make a demo today, my clip-path property does not work in amp-animation, that is, there are no changes on the page. Does clip-path work for you?

Comment: Yes. I got it kind of working in chrome. Not Safari though.
You need to reference a svg clippath element. And then transform it via the scaleX property in the animation Keyframe.

Comment: Show me your code, which I can run. Here I tried it today: https://codepen.io/alexandr-kazakov/pen/rNMbPbW My clip-path doesn't work at all. Put your code on Codepen or here so I can run it.

Comment: I have same issue, can't make clip-path work at all. In amp-animation documentation [link](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-animation/?format=websites#allowed-properties-for-keyframes) it says that clip-path is supported, though can't find any examples...